# $p$ is Prime $p \geq 5$ $\implies$ $|\{n^2 \pmod p\mid n \in [0, p-1]\}| = \frac{p+1}{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove the following claim.

> If $p$ is prime then $$|\{n^2 \pmod p\mid n \in [0, p-1]\}| = \frac{p+1}{2}$$

Where do I start? Would a proof by contradiction, contrapositive, or a direct proof be more intuitive than the other?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to be nit picky but $p=2$ is definitely a counter example

Comment: @StanTendijck the title does state that $p≥5$ but this seems to have been lost within the actual question...

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, $a^2$ and $b^2$ (wlog $a>b$) give  the same residue modulo $p$ iff $$p\mid a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)\implies p\mid a-b \vee p\mid a+b$$

But since $0<a-b<p$ we must have $p\mid a+b$ so $a+b=p$. So for each $a\ne 0$ we have exactly one $b$ such that $a+b = p$ and thus the conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Idea
$$n^2\mod p = (p - n)^2\mod p$$

Comment: I notice when I let $n = p-1$ that its the same as when $n=1$. Similarly for $n = p-k$ is equal to when $n = k$, but I'm not quite sure how to write this mathematically, or if I'm even on the right track. Intuitively I notice that the squares repeat halfway through with the exception of $0$, so that's why there are $\frac{p+1}{2}$ unique squares. But I'm still a bit confused.